# How to restore lost data in RStudio

Tags: rstudio

I have serious problem with RStudio after crash. My R file I was currently working on has been deleted. I'd like to ask who has similar problem if there's any possibility to restore that file? Basically, RStudio saved that file as 0 bytes, while I was working on it several days. Unfortunatelly didn't made any backup.

My question is: is any possibility RStudio or Windows 7 have R files in cache? 
If it was serious bug (happend first time) where should I report it?

EDIT

`.Rhistory` file has been overwritten as well as 0 byte file. The problem was probably caused by 0 bytes free-space on disk.

Please give any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have been running your R file then it should have been recorded in the .Rhistory file.

Please have a look at the link below. Basically the file stores all the commands that you've been running.

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526217-Command-History